# Aggregate as a service

Tags: domain-driven-design, axon

Assume scenario where the service requires some global configuration to handle some request.

For example when user wants to do something it requires some global configuration to check whether the user is permited todo so.

I realize that in axon i can have command handlers that could handle commands without specified target aggregate so the handling part isn't a problem.

Problem is where i would like to have persistent storage on top of that and some invariants when trying to change the configuration. The whole idea of the configuration is that it should be consistent like aggregate in axon.

```
ConfigService {
@Inject
configRepository;
@Inject
eventGateway;

@CommandHandler
handle(changeConfig){
let current = configRepository.loadCurrent;
//some checks

//persist here?
eventGateway.send(confgChanged)
}

@EventHandler
on(configChanged){
//or persist here?
configRepository.saveCurrent(configChanged.data)
}

}
```

If I do persistance on the command handler I think I shouldn't use event handler because it would save it twice. But then when i somehow lose the config repository data i can rebuild it based on the events.

Im not sure what im missing here in the understanding of the DDD concepts, to put it simply i would like to know where to put command handler for something that is neither an aggregate nor entity. 
Maybe i should create command handler that calls the Config service instead making config service the command handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you your *global configuration* is either a [specification](https://www.martinfowler.com/apsupp/spec.pdf) or a set of rules like in a [rules engine](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/RulesEngine.html).

Unlike the patterns described in [GOF book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201633612), in DDD, some building blocks/patterns are more generic and can apply to different types of object that you have.

For example an ***Entity*** is something that has a life-cycle and has an identity. The stages in the life-cycle usually are: created, persisted, reconstructed from storage, modified and then it's life cycle ends by being deleted, archived, completed etc.

A ***Value Object*** is something that doesn't have identity, (most of the time) is immutable, two instances can be compared by the equality of their properties. **Value Object** represent important concepts in our domains like: ***Money*** in system that deal with accounting, banking etc., ***Vector3*** and ***Matrix3*** in systems that do mathematical calculations and simulations like modeling systems (3dsMax, Maya), video games etc. They contain important behavior.

So everything that you need to track and has identity can be an ***Entity***.

You can have a ***Specification*** that is an entity, a ***Rule*** that is an entity, an **Event** can also be an entity if it has a unique ID assigned to it. In this case you can treat them just like any another entity. You can form aggregates, have repositories and services and use ***EventSourcing*** if necessary.

On the other hand a ***Specification***, a ***Rule***, an ***Event*** or a ***Command*** can also be ***Value Objects***.

**Specifications** and ***Rules*** can also be ***Domain Services***.

One important thing here is also the ***Bounded Context***. The system that updates these rules is probably in a different ***Bounded context*** than the system that applies there rules. It's also possible that this isn't the case.

Here's an example.

Let's have a system, where a ***Customer*** can buy stuff. This sytem will also have ***Discounts*** on ***Orders*** that have specific ***Rules***.

Let's say we have rule that says that: if a ***Customer*** has made an ***Order*** with more than 5 ***LineItems*** he get's a discount. If that ***Order*** has a total price of some amount (say 1000$) he gets discount.

The percentage of the discounts can be changed by the ***Sales team***. The ***Sales system*** has ***OrderDicountPolicy*** aggregates that it can modify. On the other hand the ***Ordering system*** only reads ***OrderDicountPolicy*** aggregates and won't be able to modify them as this is the responsibility of the ***Sales team***.

The ***Sales system*** and the ***Ordering system*** can be part of two separate ***Bounded Contexts***: ***Sales*** and ***Orders***. The ***Orders Bounded Context*** depends on ***Sales Bounded Context***.

*Note: I'll skip the most implementation details and add only the relevant things to shorten and simplify this example. If it's intent is not clear, I'll edit and add more details.* ***UUID***, ***DiscountPercentage*** and ***Money*** *are value objects that I'll skip.*

```
public interface OrderDiscountPolicy {

    public UUID getID();

    public DiscountPercentage getDiscountPercentage();
    public void changeDiscountPercentage(DiscountPercentage percentage);

    public bool canApplyDiscount(Order order);
}

public class LineItemsCountOrderDiscountPolicy implements OrderDiscountPolicy {

    public int getLineItemsCount() { }

    public void changeLineItemsCount(int count) { }

    public bool canApplyDiscount(Order order) { 
        return order.getLineItemsCount() > this.getLineItemsCount();
    }

    // other stuff from interface implementation
}

public class PriceThresholdOrderDiscountPolicy implements OrderDiscountPolicy {

    public Money getPriceThreshold() { }

    public void changePriceThreshold(Money threshold) { }

    public bool canApplyDiscount(Order order) { 
        return order.getTotalPriceWithoutDiscount() > this.getPriceThreshold();
    }

    // other stuff from interface implementation
}

public class LineItem {

    public UUID getOrderID() { }
    public UUID getProductID() { }
    public Quantity getQuantity { }
    public Money getProductPrice() { } 

    public Money getTotalPrice() {
        return getProductPrice().multiply(getQuantity());
    }
}

public enum OrderStatus { Pending, Placed, Approced, Rejected, Shipped, Finalized }

public class Order {

    private UUID mID;
    private OrderStatus mStatus;
    private List<LineItem> mLineItems;
    private DscountPercentage mDiscountPercentage;

    public UUID getID() { }
    public OrderStatus getStatus() { }
    public DscountPercentage getDiscountPercentage() { };

    public Money getTotalPriceWithoutDiscount() { 
        // return sum of all line items
    }

    public Money getTotalPrice() { 
        // return sum of all line items + discount percentage
    }

    public void changeStatus(OrderStatus newStatus) { }

    public List<LineItem> getLineItems() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(mLineItems);
    }

    public LineItem addLineItem(UUID productID, Quantity quantity, Money price) {
        LineItem item = new LineItem(this.getID(), productID, quantity, price);
        mLineItems.add(item);
        return item;
    }

    public void applyDiscount(DiscountPercentage discountPercentage) {
        mDiscountPercentage = discountPercentage;
    }
}

public class PlaceOrderCommandHandler {

    public void handle(PlaceOrderCommand cmd) {

        Order order = mOrderRepository.getByID(cmd.getOrderID());

        List<OrderDiscountPolicy> discountPolicies =
             mOrderDiscountPolicyRepository.getAll();

        for (OrderDiscountPolicy policy : discountPolicies) { 

            if (policy.canApplyDiscount(order)) {
                order.applyDiscount(policy.getDiscountPercentage());
            }
        }

        order.changeStatus(OrderStatus.Placed);

        mOrderRepository.save(order);
    }
}

public class ChangeOrderDiscountPolicyPercentageHandler {

    public void handle(ChangeOrderDiscountPolicyPercentage cmd) {

        OrderDiscountPolicy policy = 
            mOrderDiscountRepository.getByID(cmd.getPolicyID());

        policy.changePercentage(cmd.getDiscountPercentage());

        mOrderDiscountRepository.save(policy);
    }
}
```

You can use ***EventSourcing*** if you think that it's appropriate for some aggregates. The [DDD book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321125215) has a chapter on *global rules* and *specifications*.

Let's take a look what whould we do in the case of a distributed application for example using microservices.

Let's say we have 2 services: ***OrdersService*** and ***OrdersDiscountService***.

There are couple of ways to implement this operation. We can use:

- Choreography with Events
- Orchestration with explicit ***Saga*** or a ***Process Manager***

Here's how we can do it if we use Choreography with Events.

1. ***CreateOrderCommand*** -> ***OrdersService*** -> ***OrderCreatedEvent***
2. ***OrderCreatedEvent*** ->  ***OrdersDiscountService*** -> ***OrderDiscountAvailableEvent*** or ***OrderDiscountNotAvailableEvent***
3. ***OrderDiscountAvailableEvent*** or ***OrderDiscountNotAvailableEvent*** -> ***OrdersService*** -> ***OrderPlacedEvent***

In this example to place the order ***OrdersService*** will wait for ***OrderDiscountNotAvailableEvent*** or ***OrderDiscountNotAvailableEvent*** so it can apply a discount before changing the status of the order to ***OrderPlaced***.

We can also use an explicit ***Saga*** to do *Orchestration* between services.

This Saga will containt the sequence of steps for the process so it can execute it.

1. ***PlaceOrderCommand*** -> ***Saga***
2. ***Saga*** asks ***OrdersDiscountService*** to see if a discount is available for that ***Order***.
3. If discount is available, ***Saga*** calls  ***OrdersService*** to apply a discount
4. ***Saga*** calls ***OrdersService*** to set the status of the ***Order*** to ***OrderPlaced***

*Note: Steps 3 and 4 can be combined*

This raises the question: *"How ***OrdersDiscountService*** get's all the necessary information for the Order to calculate discounts?"*

This can either be achieved by adding all of the information of the order in the ***Event*** that this service will receive or by having ***OrdersDiscountService*** call ***OrdersService*** to get the information.

Here's a [Great video from Martin Folwer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=STKCRSUsyP0) on Event Driven Architectures that discusses these approaches.

The advantage of *Orchestration with a* ***Saga*** is that the exact process is explicitly defined in the ***Saga*** and can be found, understood and debugged.

Having implicit processes like in the case of the *Choreography with Events* can be harder to understand, debug and maintain.

The downside of having ***Sagas*** is that we do define more things.

Personally, I tend to go for the explicit ***Saga*** especially for complex processes, but most of the systems I work and see use both approaches.

Here are some additional resources:

https://blog.couchbase.com/saga-pattern-implement-business-transactions-using-microservices-part/

https://blog.couchbase.com/saga-pattern-implement-business-transactions-using-microservices-part-2/

https://microservices.io/patterns/data/saga.html

[The LMAX Architecture](https://martinfowler.com/articles/lmax.html) is very interesting read. It's not distributed system, but is event driven and records both incomming events/commands and outgoint events. It's an interesting way to capture everything that happend in a system or a service.

Comment: Thank you for another extensive answer, helps alot!

Just a small follow-up question, if you could check if my thinking is right. Considering the microservice scenario in your presented example of orders and discounts, since i would't mix the repositories in the codebases the PlaceOrderCommand would basically start saga  and ask the Discount service what kind of discounts are available for the order. So then the discount service would just need to listen for order creation events and build their own 'image' of the orders that are going to ask it about the discounts available for them?

Comment: You're welcome. happy to help :) Sorry.. I should have added the distributed case too. I'll add an edit to my answer. Your thinking is right :) Just one thing about the 'ímage' in the DiscountService. If you wan't to have a record of processed orders in that service you can record such images. On the other hand this service can calculate discounts when someone ask it (for example the Saga) and return them without storing any information thus saving storage space. How you do it will depend on how complext the case is. In this example I think that it's not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Axon without event sourcing here?

In Axon framework it is generally good practice only to change the state of an aggregate with events. If you are going to mix state or configuration loaded from a repository with state from the event store, how will you be able to guarantee that when you replay the same events, the resulting state will be the same? The next time the aggregate is loaded, there may be different state in your configRepository, resulting in a different state and different behavior of your aggregate.

Why is this bad? Well, those same events may have been handled by eventprocessors, they may have filled query tables, they may have sent messages to other systems or done other work based on the state the system had at the time. You will have a disagreement between your query database and your aggregate.

A concrete example: Imagine your aggregate processed a command to switch an email service on. The aggregate did this by applying an EmailServiceEnabledEvent and changing its own state to 'boolean emailEnabled = true'. After a while, the aggregate gets unloaded from memory. Now you change that configurationRepository to disable switching the email service on. When the aggregate is loaded again, events from the event store are applied, but this time it loads the configuration from your repository that says it shouldn't switch the email service on. The 'boolean emailEnabled' state is left false. You send a disable email service command to the aggregate, but the command handler in the aggregate thinks the email is already disabled, and doesn't apply an EmailServiceDisabledEvent. The email service is left on.

In short: I would recommend using commands to change the configuration of your aggregate.